# Allow to use http repository from repostories file

Tags: sbt

I've updated to SBT 1.3.0. Now I keep receiving warning on every action:

```
[warn] insecure HTTP request is deprecated 'http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("nexus" at "http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
```

I've tried following options in **~/.sbt/repositories** file:

```
nexus: ("http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
```

and

```
("nexus" at "http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
```

How can I allow http repositories **globally** (for all configured repositories)?

Comment: Does this repository support HTTPS?

Comment: No, it supports HTTP only.

Answer (score 3):

create **~/.sbt/resolvers.sbt** and add there

```
resolvers += ("nexus" at "http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
```

or

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  ("nexus" at "http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true),
  ("nexus" at "http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true),
...
)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer! Sadly, this doesn't work for me: 1. When I leave `repositories` file - nothing changes (warning still exists), 2. if I make `repositories` file empty - I got a lot of dependency resolution errors 3. If I remove `repositories` file and leave only `resolvers.sbt` - Sbt resolves some dependencies (from Maven resolver added in project), but fails on others  - seems like this `~/.sbt/resolvers.sbt` file is just ignore in my case. Any ideas why it may happen?

Answer (score 2):

in your `.sbt/repositories` file, you can add setting using comma:

```sh
[repositories]
  nexus: http://<company_domain>/nexus/content/repositories/mvnrepository/, allowInsecureProtocol
```

look at pattern in [sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html):

```
name: url(, pattern)(,bootOnly)(,descriptorOptional)(,skipConsistencyCheck)(,allowInsecureProtocol)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this also, but in looking at the SBT source code, I saw that if you are using a version of the SBT launcher prior to 1.3.11, it automatically defaults "allowInsecureProtocol" to false and issues no warning.  See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/7969a155b0978a925d3bd4aeefcb2ace163835db/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L4155

Importantly, this depends on the launcher, which is the version of SBT you actually have installed.  Your build file may reference a later version that does support this field, but if the launcher is below 1.13.11 you will see this issue.  You can check your version by running the command line:

```
sbt --version
```

The solution is to upgrade the version of SBT you have installed.  Once I upgraded the following line worked successfully in my repositories file:

my-releases: http://artifactory.mydomain.net:8080/artifactory/sbt-release/,allowInsecureProtocol

Answer (score 0):

If you use IDEA, my answer may be helpful. It finds out on sbt shell start IDEA overrode the version from 1.3.12 to 1.5.5
I told IDEA not to override my project sbt version and then allowInsecureProtocol worked correctly used with a pattern suggested by Boris Azanov